# Show all open sockets in Python

Tags: python, sockets

In Python 2.7 is there a way to get information on all open sockets similar to what netstat/ss does in linux?

I am interested in writing a small program (similar to EtherApe) that tracks when my computer opens a connection to a server.

Comment: What is the OS? On Windows, you can call Winapi functions from python, so you can do everything a C program can do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least on Linux, `netstat` works by examining the data in [procfs](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) files such as `/proc/net/tcp`. There is, unfortunately, no OS-independent way of getting this data.

Comment: Thank you. I found a module that was able to access the information there.  For future reference it is at https://github.com/pmuller/procfs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) Python library. If you want to just list the open sockets for the current Python process:

```
import psutil

p = psutil.Process()
p.connections(kind='inet')
```

If you want to list all open sockets on the machine then you can use the call [net_connections()](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.net_connections) (Note: On certain platforms (i.e MacOS and AIX) you will need to run it as root):

```
psutil.net_connections(kind='inet')
```

Answer (score -1):

Sockets are handled and controlled by OS. Any programming language what do is just put the data to buffer in OS. So in order to check the open sockets you just have to read them by operating system.